# The Viewmodel is not destroyed even when the oncleared is called

Tags: kotlin, navigation

there is a Nested graph inside them two fragments (A,B) with 3 viewmodels
1 sharedviewmodel and 2 individual
the individual viewmodel is not getting destroyed even when the   findNavController().popBackStack()
is called which inturn calls onCleared  of viewmodel

this is initialization inside one of the fragment
B'sVm =
ViewModelProvider(this).get(B'sViewModel::class.java)

There is a recyclerview inside the B's fragment which take the list from viewmodel(through binding) (after network call) then called findNavController().popBackStack() to go to A's Fragment(the onCleared of viewmodel is called ) Then navigated to Fragment B . the previous list is still there .

Fragment A->Fragment B(list the data) -> Fragemnt A-> Fragment B(previous list still there )